# Get text by line number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

What is the easiest way to get the whole line of text having line number/where the mouse caret is? (In currently open document.)

I'm getting line number using:

```
 DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
 int line = ((EnvDTE.TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection).ActivePoint.Line;
```

also using similar approach I can get selected text:

```
string line = ((EnvDTE.TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection).Text;
```

but I'm struggling to find anything that could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the whole line of text where the caret is:

```
var activePoint = ((EnvDTE.TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection).ActivePoint;
string text = activePoint.CreateEditPoint().GetLines(activePoint.Line, activePoint.Line + 1);
```